# Chrome uncaught error with no details?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I get this error without any other info (not even what type of error it is) and I cannot figure out where it's at, because it doesn't say the line of code that has the error.

Firefox doesn't show any errors in my code.

I'm using the Google Maps API and jQuery in the code.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you see any errors in the network tab?

Comment: no... no error in network tab.

Comment: something really odd here because a simple document like
    <html>
        <body>
            test
        </body>
    </html>
gives "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject."

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'sdc'
window.onunload"

Comment: so weird, even here in this page I get the error on chrome's console... I am using chrome version 28.0.1500.72 m

Comment: yeah, i'm starting to think this has something to do with the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a syntax error in your codes. You can check your codes with an intelligent IDE like NetBeeans. It checks your codes dynamically and reports errors. Also please try to enable Firefox Script tab.

Comment: How does this answer the question? This should be a comment

Comment: i use phpstorm with all javascript inspections active... also, i checked my code twice but couldn't find a single issue with it. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd check and see what extensions/toolbars you've got installed in Chrome. Behavior like this can sometimes be caused by an extension running "extra" code on all of the sites you visit.

SIDE NOTE: A site that I work on is seeing these same kinds of errors reported up through our client-side error-logging system, and I'd love to know what was causing this for our users!

Comment: Chris, this happens in 2 of my 3 installations of chrome... in all of them i have only adblock plus and a home banking extension installed... even disabling both extensions and restarting the browser, the problem persists... i didn't try uninstalling chrome, but i assume that will eliminate the problem without a solution.